# How can I decrease compile time of TMP & macro preprocessor metaprogramming in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, profiling

Are there any tricks that can work with large pile of metaprogramming code?

I'm using the latest version of clang. But I can switch to any (free) compiler that support C++14.

Comment: Alternative close reason: Asking for off site tools ...

Comment: Or, are there any tricks that can work with large pile of metaprogramming code? I am also asking for a method. But thank for noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or, are there any tricks that can work with large pile of
>   metaprogramming code?

Prefer `constexpr`-functions to TMP-functions, they are generally faster. Since C++14 you can also use more than only a return-statement of working code in constexpr-functions, that eases their use even more.
Generally avoid recursion. And don't care about the complexity class of the algorithm itself too much, as long as it compiles fast. (In TMP code, getting the better complexity class can result in much slower compilation).

**Don't use recursion with variadic templates like so:**

```
template< typename First, typename ... Tail >
struct A : A<Tail...>
```

They create a quadratic time complexity, because the compiler has to create separate argument lists in every step! This is significantly measurable. Try instead to delegate recursion to one point in the program, the best approach is to delegate it to [`std::make_index_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence), and then deduce everything to that.

Don't use Boost.PP to generate many partial/explicit specializations which handle cases. It doesn't help. 200 explicit spezializations will only make it worse, since the compiler has to search through the spezializations (beside the primary template) and look for the first and most specialized one which matches.